# Joomla two module using same helper.php

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions

I've built two custom  modules for Joomla ("reservation" and "contact") which are working just fine, however time to time I have to upgrade them. 
Is it possible to make them to share the same "helper.php" so I could keep code in one place? For example the *post* function is the same for these two modules. I want the "contact" module to use the "reservation" helper.php post function.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply include the reservation module helper inside the contact module and use it.
For example lets say that your modules are mod_reservation and mod_contact, in mod_contact.php you include the reservation helper file and use it like this:

```
require_once JPATH_SITE.DS."modules".DS."mod_reservation".DS."helper.php";
modReservationHelper::post();
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you make a custom helper module,, which is needed in order for the other 2 to work. I dont know for sure but I thought you can check for other modules when installing a module. In that check you check for the helper module and if not present you give a error. You could also say that a certain module needs atleast version X.XX.XX of the helper module and if the version is too long also give an error in during the install of the module.