# How to start count chars avoiding <img></img> tag, but leaving it in text ? in joomla

Tags: php, joomla

I used this

```
$item->introtext = JHtml::_('content.prepare', $item->introtext);
$item->introtext = strip_tags($item->introtext);
$item->introtext = substr($item->introtext, 0, 50);
```

But then only plain text appears without image.. I want to count characters after the img tag, but still have the img tag in text after counting.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the `<img></img>` and its position in the string in an array, then reinsert it after the count.

Comment: What function I should use for that? And - I tryied storing my own custom string in joomla module helper.php file, but it had no effect  when used in tmpl files ( i.e echo $customstring; )

Comment: It you are creating a module, check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903197/joomla-two-module-using-same-helper-php